# Nav bar menu in css3

Tags: html, css

This is what I want to do:

[image: here]

**sample code:**

```
  #mainnav-menu {
            float: left;
            width: 101%;
            list-style-type: none;
            list-style-position: outside;
            position: relative;
            background-color: #389c0c;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 8px -6px black;
               -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 8px -6px black;
                    box-shadow: 0 10px 8px -6px black;
        }
        #mainnav-menu li {
            float:left;
            position:relative;
            margin-right: 1px;
        }
        #mainnav-menu a {
            display: block;
            padding: 0.8em 1.2em;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 1.1em;
            font-family: 'Carme', Tahoma, Verdana, Arial;
            color: #bde8a9;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
            -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
            -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
            transition: all 0.1s ease-out;  
        }
        #mainnav-menu a:link, #mainnav-menu a:visited{
            color: #bde8a9;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        #mainnav-menu a:hover {
            color: #64c937;
            background: #0088ff; 
        }
        #mainnav-menu ul {
            position: absolute;
            display: none;
            z-index: 99;
            background: #0088ff;
        }
        #mainnav-menu ul li{
            margin: 0;
        }
        #mainnav-menu ul a {
            width: 250px;
            width: 16rem;
            padding: 0.7em 1.3em;
            float: left;
            font-weight: normal;
            color: #fff;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        #mainnav-menu ul a:link, #mainnav-menu ul a:visited{
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 1.0em;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        #mainnav-menu li ul ul {
            margin-left: 250px;
            margin-left: 16rem;
        }

        #wrapper {
            max-width: 1000px;
            width: 92%;
            margin: 0 auto 5em;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            background: #00F;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #888;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px#888;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px #888; 
        }
```

**HTML:**

```
    <header id="header" class="container clearfix" role="banner">

    <div id="logo">

    </div>
</header>

<h3 id="mainnav-icon">Menu</h3><nav id="mainnav" class="container clearfix" role="navigation">
    <ul id="mainnav-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-62" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-62"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-63" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-63"><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-65" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-65"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

        </ul>   </nav>


     </div>
```

jsfiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/whws8/2/)

My problem is, I can't make the left side of the nav bar to extend. Any ideas? I'd gladly apprecite. Thanks.

**NOTE:**

I don't want to use any extra image, I just want to do this in pure css.

Comment: What do you mean by 'extend'? Could you elaborate please?

Comment: I mean both sides should extend and just equal to the wrapper.

Comment: what you want to extend? the menu or header?

Comment: @Mr_Green I'm referring to the menu/nav bar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using `:after` and `:before` pseudo element selectors.

### CSS

```
#mainnav{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#mainnav:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: -25px;
    bottom: -3px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent green;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 20px;    
}
#mainnav:after{
    content: "";
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    bottom: -4px;
    border-color: transparent green transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/whws8/4/)

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you want to make a css3 ribbon. You can use this guide: http://www.andreapinchi.it/css3-ribbon/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this? (apply it to your fiddle):

```
#mainnav-menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #389c0c;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 8px -6px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 8px -6px black;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 8px -6px black;
}
#mainnav-menu li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 1px;
}
#mainnav-menu a {
    padding: 0 1.2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-family:'Carme', Tahoma, Verdana, Arial;
    color: #bde8a9;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
}
#mainnav-menu a:link, #mainnav-menu a:visited {
    color: #bde8a9;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#mainnav-menu a:hover {
    color: #64c937;
    background: #0088ff;
}
#mainnav-menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 99;
    background: #0088ff;
}
#mainnav-menu ul a {
    width: 250px;
    width: 16rem;
    padding: 0.7em 1.3em;
    float: left;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#mainnav-menu ul a:link, #mainnav-menu ul a:visited {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 92%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #00F;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px#888;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #888;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the  answer, but as you can see in the screenshot I posted, it is very different. Take a close look at the screenshot, you can notice the corners of the navbar

Comment: @Dunkey Sorry, the screenshot didn't load for me. I guess I wasn't sure what you were going for. Check out gray's answer, it might be what you need

Answer (score -1):

Answer is Here

http://jsfiddle.net/whws8/5/

if you want to create the Image You need to use CSS like this

```
#clip
{
position: absolute;
top: 23px;
left:-5px;
display: inline-block;
border-bottom: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
border-right: 12px solid #1F1FC1;
border-left: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
content: '';}
```

Comment: @Dunkey please check this answer, and if this answer help full to you, please let me know